# MS Excel how to proporationately spread $ values over years

Tags: excel-formula

Hi All and thank you in advance for any help.

I have several projects that start and finish in different years and want to spread the contract value proportionately over each year. For example a project might start on 1 July 2020 and end 30 June 2022 with a value of $20 million. So how would I automatically populate a value for each of these years, this example would have $5m in 2020, $10m in 2021 and $5m in 2022. The issue is I have about 100 projects that have started since 2013 and some are not due to finish until 2024 so some degree of auomation will help me. I have set up a spread sheet as follows

[Excel spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCzDR.png)

Hope this makes sense and any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,

Try the following formula in the "Contract Days per Year":

> =MAX(0,MIN(DATE(E$1,12,31),$B3)-MAX(DATE(E$1,1,1),$A3)+1)

[image]

Then you will just multiply the result in the "Contract Value by Year"

for 2019 year, copy the values under 2018 and paste it under 2019

hope it helped